# `flask db upgrade` runs fine, but subsequent calls to `flask db migrate` drop all tables

Tags: python, flask, flask-migrate

At some point I was able to use the `flask db` CLI to generate my initial data model migration. My application is Dockerized, and when I start it up I call `flask db upgrade` in `entrypoint.sh` which echos:

```
backend_1   | INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl MySQLImpl.
backend_1   | INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume non-transactional DDL.
backend_1   | INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade  -> 7f973d2726ef, initial data model
```

So that's great. I have now made updates to the data model and want to create a migration, exactly like I was able to before, with `flask db migrate -m 'update games tables'`, which echos:

```
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl MySQLImpl.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume non-transactional DDL.
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected removed table 'games'
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected removed table 'game_status'
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected removed table 'positions'
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected removed table 'users'
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected removed table 'game_invites'
  Generating /home/backend/database/migrations/versions/55f785302c18_update_games_tables.py ...  done
```

My `flask db migrate` command sees the database tables, but since it isn't reading any model data it thinks that we want to delete them all. I'm really stumped on this one. The most recent post I checked out was [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54632694/models-are-not-detectable-by-flask-migrate). Per Miguel's troubleshooting suggestions in the post, I have:

- Verified that I am using the same `db` across the entire application context (see below)
- Explicitly imported all data models prior to calling `migrate.init_app`
- Torn down and rebuild my database multiple times, including re-starting the migrations directory with `flask db init`

My directory structure looks like this, and I'll include what I think are the most important snippets of code below:

```
/backend/
|       |__/__init__.py (empty)
|       |__/app_factory.py
|       |__/backend-entrypoint.sh
|       |__/wsgi.py
|       |__/config.py
|       |__/.flaskenv
|
|__/api (nothing important here)
|
|__/database/
|           |__/migrations/... (all the usual stuff here)
|           |__/db.py
|           |__/models.py
|
|__/tests (nothing important here)
```

**db.py**

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy() # <- This is the db that's going to get passed around
```

**models.py**

```
from aenum import Enum

from backend.database.db import db


class Users(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "users"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.Text)
    email = db.Column(db.Text)
    profile_pic = db.Column(db.Text)
    username = db.Column(db.Text)
    created_at = db.Column(db.DATETIME)
...
# Here's the part where I'm making changes to the schema.
```

**app_factory.py**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_migrate import Migrate

from database.db import db
from api import routes as routes


def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object('config.Config')
    db.init_app(app)
    migrate = Migrate()

    with app.app_context():
        app.register_blueprint(routes.routes)
        # It's annoying that flask works this way. migrate and models both become part of the application context here
        from backend.database.models import (
            Users,
            Games,
            GameStatus,
            GameInvites,
            Positions
        )
        migrate.init_app(app, db, directory="/home/backend/database/migrations")
        return app
```

**backend-entrypoint.sh**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
until nc -z -v -w30 $DB_HOST 3306
do
  echo "Waiting a second until the database is receiving connections..."
  sleep 1
done

flask db upgrade # construct the data model

python wsgi.py # start the web application
```

**wsgi.py**

```
from backend.app_factory import create_app

from config import Config

app = create_app()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=Config.DEBUG_MODE, ssl_context=("cert.pem", "key.pem"))
```

**config.py**

```
...
class Config:
    ...
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = f"mysql+pymysql://{db_user}:{db_password}@{db_host}:{db_port}/{db_name}?charset=utf8"
...
```

**.flaskenv**

```
FLASK_APP=/home/backend/wsgi.py
```

This worked at some point, but nothing I've tried today, including tearing down the entire db, rebuilding the container, and starting from scratch with `flask db init` has gotten my anywhere. The problem doesn't seem to be that the changes aren't being detected, but that `flask db` isn't even connecting to the right database, even though I setup `Migrate` within the flask app context. I have functional tests that I run against the API server that the flask app runs, and it has no issue communicating with the populated database. The problem seems pretty contained to the `flask db` CLI. I have tried rolling back to earlier versions to see if I can identify whether a change in my file structure broke something, but this issue is persisting across multiple commits.

Comment: Can i ask why do you have db.drop_all() in your create_app() file?. Wouldn't that command drop all the tables whenever you run that function which is whenever you are starting your application?

Comment: @prajwalkHebbar good catch -- that line is just an artifact of some debugging I've been doing. It doesn't remove the tables. Doesn't seem to have any effect at all, in fact, which I agree is weird. In either case, I've edited the question. Still having the same issue.

Comment: I think you are interpreting what's happening backwards. Your migration suggests deleting all your tables not because it cannot access the database. It obviously can, because it can see those tables and wants to delete them. The problem is that none of the models are visible, so the migration tries to adapt your database to an application that has no SQLAlchemy models defined. Try importing your models, it is not sufficient to have them defined, they need to be imported so that they get registered with SQLAlchemy.

Comment: Thank you, @Miguel. But doesn't the `from backend.database.models import (...` code block immediately before `migrate.init_app` achieve this? If not here, where else do I need to be importing the models?

Comment: Well, I'm just telling what's happening. I hope you agree that your analysis was backwards and that for a yet to be discovered reason your models aren't being seen by SQLAlchemy and thus by Alembic. Your create_app function is actually strange, you shouldn't need to create a context in there. Also odd that you import your models there, they should be imported in the global scope, so that the import happens earlier.

Comment: @Miguel working on this now and yep, I completely agree that my analysis was backwards: the app clearly has awareness of the tables. So somehow the model import isn't working. I'll keep playing around with it in app_factory, and failing that will make another pass at the flask mega tutorial

Comment: Sorted, thanks @Miguel

Answer (score 0):

Got it sorted out just by cleaning up the layout of `create_app.py`. Thanks to @Miguel for the pointers on this. The issue seems to have been 1) Inappropriate use of `app_context` and 2) the import order of `models`. When I strip out the `with app.app_context()` line and move my model imports to the bottom I get something that works great:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_migrate import Migrate

from backend.database.db import db
from backend.api import routes as routes
from config import Config


def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object('config.Config')
    app.register_blueprint(routes.routes)
    db.init_app(app)
    migrate = Migrate(app, db, directory=Config.MIGRATIONS_DIRECTORY)
    migrate.init_app(app, db)
    return app

from backend.database import models
```

I used [the `__init__` file from Miguel's Flask Mega Tutorial](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/microblog/blob/master/app/__init__.py) for this. The two main ways that my architecture is different than his is that I create my `db` object in a separate file (see above) to avoid circular imports when using elsewhere (e.g. in my api routes definitions), and I define a `create_app.py` file rather than placing all the app setup in `__init__`